# Getting pie chart values dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

This is my pie chart js code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var pieData = [
                {
                    value: 300,
                    color:getRandomColor(),
                    highlight: "#62b9fb",
                },
                {
                    value: 50,
                    color: "#ffb53e",
                    highlight: "#fac878",
                },
                {
                    value: 100,
                    color: "#1ebfae",
                    highlight: "#3cdfce",
                },
                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: "#f9243f",
                    highlight: "#f6495f",
                }

            ];

    var chart4 = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(chart4).Pie(pieData, {
        responsive : true
    });

};
```

I am using [this](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options) javascript pluging. My pie chart it works but its values is gives statically. I believe that I have to use an ajax, which is not a problem. My problem is how can I  create the **piedata** data format after I decoded the json and how can I create the color? I have to generate randomly colors? Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Colors is easy.. but if you don't want to create your data in javascript, where would your data come from? Where do you want to pull from?

Comment: I want to extract the data from db

Comment: okk.... what kind of database, where is it coming from?

Comment: it is mysql in comes from a table called diagnosis, but that does not matter. My problem is how can i generate that  var pieData after I decoded the json

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't fully understand your question; but..

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors, // references stock colors defined in highcharts.js
    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
    name = 'Browser brands',
    data = [{
        y: 55.11,
        color: colors[0], // references stock color highcharts.js from color array
        drilldown: {
            name: 'MSIE versions',
            categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'], // JS data arrays
            data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81], // data areas 
            color: colors[0] // references stock color highcharts.js color array
        }
    },
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoeKuan/6NJcM/)

For custom colors, outside of what is given to choose from via highcharts.js download that full js. Locate color array in there, and define your own via hex and call them.

If you need to pull data from a specific place, you need to specify..

**Sample of an AJAX call with the chart:**

```
var GetChartData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceUri,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (d) {
           chartData = {
                labels: d.AxisLabels,
                datasets: [
                    {
```

Comment: well there is a lot of stuff in your fiddle, but my data comes from db , and i don't see any ajax there

Comment: That's too vague man... a DB? an api? from microsoft access, have no idea what your doing..

Comment: Just gave you a sample of an ajax call.